# Windows Server 2008: how to remove "favorite links" from Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-server-2008

I just set up a fresh install of Windows Server 2008, and have a favorite links pane above folders in my Explorer.  I know I can drag folders over it, but it comes back, and looks funky.

How can I really just disable that? Anyone know where it is in the registry?

Comment: are you speaking of the navigation pane on the LHS in explorer? or the favorites bar in internet explorer? a screenshot may help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [article](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/69146-navigation-pane-vista-windows-explorer.html) that describes disabling it in Vista.  The steps should be the same in Windows 2008.

Comment: Really seems like there should be a way to just get rid of the favorites and keep the folder tree...

Comment: agree, Windows Server 2008 is the same GUI base as Vista, and Windows Server 2008 R2 is the same GUI base as Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

By default, Windows Server 2008 R2 does not provides Group Policy to disable or turn off Favorites and Libraries feature in Explorer. You can modify registry key to hide them.

Note: Please backup the key first.

1. For Favorites, the key is:

   ```
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}\ShellFolder]

   "Attributes"=dword:a0900100
   ```

   Changing `a0900100` to `a9400100` will hide Favorites from Navigation Pane.
2. For Libraries, the key is:

   ```
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}\ShellFolder]

   "Attributes"=dword:b080010d
   ```

   Changing `b080010d` to `b090010d` will hide Libraries from Navigation Pane.

Note: You need to take ownership the ShellFolder before changing the value of Attributes.